# Custom Elements v1 feature detection: Message for non-supporting browsers

Tags: web-component, custom-element

I am developing Custom Elements for supported browsers only

Looking for a not too complex Custom Elements feature detection method,
I came up with:

```
<STYLE onload="if('customElements' in window)this.innerHTML=''">
 body::before {
  font-size: 2em;
  color: red;
  content: 'This Browser does NOT support modern W3C WebComponents (Custom Elements v1)';
 }
</STYLE>
```

I am not 100% sure; this approach might flash the text (very very briefly)

**Question:** Is there a more elegant solution to do Custom Element feature detection?

### ---

qomponents

Answer (score 1):

Protect the CSS by using a class or something else then have the JS code add the needed class if the condition is right:

```html
<script>
if(!('customElements' in window)) {
  document.body.classList.add('no-web-components');
}
</script>

<style>
 body.no-web-components::before {
  font-size: 2em;
  color: red;
  content: 'This Browser does NOT support modern W3C WebComponents (Custom Elements v1)';
 }
</style>
```

> Also, if you plan to do this you might want to also provide a link to a page showing them where to download a better browser.

Comment: tnx, But what does it protect against?

Comment: If you use a class and then have the JS set or reset that class then there is less likelihood of something flashing when the page loads.

Comment: Now I see; the script is executed before the style is loaded. tnx